# Using perl_set in nginx with perl module

Tags: html, perl, http, nginx, perl-module

Having this in nginx configuration file:

```
http {
    perl_modules perl/lib;
    perl_require utiles.pm;
    perl_set $user_perfil utiles::get_perfil;
}
```

If i use the ssi variable "user_perfil" in a html page, like this:

```
<!--# echo var="user_perfil" -->
```

everytime when i do that, nginx calls the function 'utiles::get_perfil' ? or just the first time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function will run everytime when variable is using;

Comment: even when are mutiple calls in the same page ?

Comment: no, it will call the function only first time, if variable used twice or more;